# Button text not displaying in safari, displaying in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The text of button is not displaying in Safari,I can return the text using jquery in the console. But it is recognising the click event e.g

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
<button onclick="change();" id="face-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Face</button>
```

Comment: Is it only in Safari? Did you try adding `z-index` to it?

Comment: remove type="button" from button tag. It's not required. Changes css for #face-btn{ color: '#000000'; }

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion tried both neither are working. Only in Safari.

Comment: Do you have a link I can go to? I'm sure I can help you if I could open the dev tools and have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Issue was with the line -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

Comment: Could you please add details.

Comment: Very underrated answer. I added `-webkit-text-fill-color: black` and the button text appeared. This override was needed only in iOS versions 15.5 and above; on iOS 14.5, the button text showed without having to add this override.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't write a comment that why am writing a suggestion here,
try to add a height to your button style
This answer is based on this Articel: [Button-not-displaying-well-in-Safari](https://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?597261-Button-not-displaying-well-in-Safari)

Comment: CSS Code .btn {
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
            background-image: linear-gradient(79deg, var(--greenblue), var(--macaroni-and-cheese));
            border-radius: 60px;
            color: var(--white);
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 12.8px;
            line-height: 32px;
            margin-bottom: 1rem;
            min-width: 120px;
            padding: 0 6px;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none
        }

Answer (score 0):

I am using Safari browser and I can see the text in the button.
For better support use `value` attribute to provide support for all browsers.

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
<button onclick="change();" id="face-btn" type="button" value="Face" class="btn btn-primary">Face</button>
```

Hope it helps.